# CodeIgniter not inserting urls to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently building an API using the CodeIgniter framework. I have run into an issue and can't find an answer anywhere.

Currently when my end point gets called to post data it requires a URL to be saved to my DB however the format of the URL gets broken when being inserted.

In my request the URL looks like this:

```
web_url: "https://someurl.com"
```

However in my DB it looks like this:

`https // google.com`

Also, when really long URLs are inserted only a small part of the URL is saved. Here is an example:

Original

```
https://some.service.com/source/update?user=116&subscription=186248&hash=eyJpdiI6IlpSZytyMXI5NFE2XC80Qmc3MTJMREJHVHgyR2dlQU5NakxEbFFWM2Fsb0hNPSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWdBT0FrZGFYNkw0cllzcXRRcitvMUFRMDNSaFwveVR6bXVRODlSUFM5MUt6aFQzSDNiczJoRUVzdUZ3VE11MHZjWnFnYzNOUUMyTmxmRnpHNVQ0alF3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5NjBlMmI3YTZlMzk2MzU1ZmUxMTI3ZTViODQwMTEyYmQ5NTU4OTc5MTg3Mzk1YzBkZWZkODIxOTQzNTNkYmUyIn0%253D
```

DB:

`https //some.service.com/source/update?user=116&subscripti`

In my DB the URL field is set as`varchar(1000)`

Here is my code that I am using to store the URL:

```
if ($status == "active")
    {
        $user_id = $this->post('user_id');
        $update_url = $this->post('update_url');
        $cancel_url = $this->post('cancel_url');
        $account = array("status" => $status, 
            "user_id" => $user_id, 
            "update_url" => $update_url,
            "cancel_url" => $cancel_url);

            $this->db->insert('accounts', $account);
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try to use mysql_real_escape_string() function?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using mysql_real_escape_string() but that doesn't help

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong in your code. Maybe you should add the code to your question.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by using `$data = $this->input->post();` to get all the data in the post request rather then getting each individual element.

Appears to be working now :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can change the datatype of your field to `text`

Comment: @user1195300 can you post part of your code, the one that saves to your db so we can help better

Comment: @user1195300 when you print `$update_url` does it give the correct url ?

Comment: When I print update URL it looks like this: `https \/\/some.service.com\/account\/update?user=9&subscripti` however it looks like this in the request `https://some.service.com/source/update?user=116&subscription=186248&hash=eyJpdiI6IlpSZytyMXI5NFE2XC80Qmc3MTJMREJHVHgyR2dlQU5NakxEbFFWM2Fsb0hNPSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWdBT0FrZGFYNkw0cllzcXRRcitvMUFRMDNSaFwveVR6bXVRODlSUFM5MUt6aFQzSDNiczJoRUVzdUZ3VE11MHZjWnFnYzNOUUMyTmxmRnpHNVQ0alF3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5NjBlMmI3YTZlMzk2MzU1ZmUxMTI3ZTViODQwMTEyYmQ5NTU4OTc5MTg3Mzk1YzBkZWZkODIxOTQzNTNkYmUyIn0%253D`

Comment: So your problem starts during the passing of the `POST` data. Were you using ajax during submit?

Comment: The `$update_url` comes from a third party service which is sending the information to my end point. When I use their simulator it shows the request as sending the full url